# How to set up a Minecraft profile specifically for NEI?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-launcher

I want to be able to play with NEI and leave the other mods in the mods folder. I was told that I can "just make a separate profile containing only Forge and Not Enough Items."

How can I do this? I understand that I need to make a new profile then somehow connect Not Enough Items to it. I have tried making a new profile in the launcher and set the version to the last available one for Forge, but I can't find where to put the mod.

Comment: What have you tried?  As I have said before, we don't mind helping people, but we *do* expect them to attempt to help themselves.  What effort have you made towards figuring this out on your own?  Give us a starting point to help you, not, "Someone said I could do X.  How do I do that?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of what you've done is correct. Create the profile and set the version to Forge. However, you also need to give the profile a **custom game directory**.

[image]

<sup>In the above example, I've appended `/forgenei` as my custom folder.</sup>

Next, launch Minecraft so it can do its configuring, then quit it. Go to the profile's folder using the Open Game Dir button and place the NEI jar in the mods folder, then launch Minecraft. This mods folder (in forgenei in my example) is specific to this profile.